# How to fix "No module named 'nredarwin'" ImportError in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, importerror

I'm trying to access the Darwin feed from National Rail Enquiries in Python 3.5.3 on my Raspberry Pi. I'm trying to use a module called [nre-darwin-py](https://github.com/robert-b-clarke/nre-darwin-py) but after I've installed it using `pip install nre-darwin-py` (with and without `sudo`) I'm getting an `ImportError` when I try to import it in my program when using Python 3 (IDLE).

However, when I run python inside the command prompt I am able to import the module and try to use it, it works! I am also able to run some of the provided example code in the command prompt but not inside Python 3.

The code I'm using to import it is:

```py
from nredarwin.webservice import DarwinLdbSession
```

but that's copied straight from the example code provided.

The code is running in a file called `nre testing.py` in `/home/pi/Station Departures`. From questions I've previously found here, the module has been installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` which I think is what's causing the problem as I'm running Python 3.5.3.

I've tried installing the module using `python -m pip install nre-darwin-py` with and without `sudo` but the command prompt returns

```
Requirement already satisfied: nre-darwin-py in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: suds-jurko in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from nre-darwin-py)
```

So the pi thinks that the module has been installed successfully (`suds-jerko` is a required module it installs)

I'm afraid I have so far been unable to find a solution so any help is most welcome.

Comment: try `python3 -m`... or `pip3 install`...

Comment: @Chris_Rands just tried that: the files have now been put in `/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages` but still the same error